# jQuery - Multiple setInterval Conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict, setinterval

I am a jQuery novice and each of the following work fine on their own, but get out of time when working together. What am I doing wrong? Any improvement on the code would be appreciated too... It is to be used to rotate advertising.

```
<!--- Header Rotator --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header").load("header.cfm");
    var refreshHeader = setInterval(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.cfm");
    }, 10000);
});
</script>
<!--- Main Rotator --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load("main.cfm");
    var refreshMain = setInterval(function() {
        $("#main").load("main.cfm");
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
<!--- Footer Rotator --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#footer").load("footer.cfm");
    var refreshFooter = setInterval(function() {
        $("#footer").load("footer.cfm");
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: In what way do they get out of order? If it's just refreshing content in multiple places, do they have to be exact order? They seem to have different times anyways?

Comment: try and debug by adding a `console.log()` in them and see which one gets out of order when, otherwise it's a bit difficult to tell whats going on because everything looks fine. On another note, this seems very heavy on the server to keep polling like that, can't you retrieve like 100 ads and then just switch them locally in the browser?

Comment: @Oscar Godson and @davin - Order is not the issue. Timing is the issue

Comment: @davin - How heavy is this on a server? Is it something to worry about? The content changes according to client and irregular criteria, so cannot be cached

Comment: @Chris, if you add the `console.log()` you might just see what causes the timing to go off track - it's possible that it just takes time to load from the server, so while the code works perfectly, it takes time to load, which causes delays and makes it appear to be off timing. This off course would be solved if you could, as per my first suggestion, load many at once, that way the switching could be local and much faster.

Comment: @Chris, secondly, regarding the polling, it is heavy on the server. How heavy? That depends on what your traffic is like, and what server/stack you're running on etc. With the code above every user makes 8 round-trip calls to the server every 10 seconds, so if you've got 100 concurrent users that stay on the site for a minute, even though they all load just 1 page, that's almost 5000 requests from the server. That's not too much to handle, although it's getting there. And if you have more than 100? In short, it won't scale well.

Comment: @davin - Due to your concerns of server overload, and now mine, I have changed tack and decided to stick with only the main content refreshing. Further...  I didn't get around to using the console.log(), but can confirm, the loading originally worked fine on a test site with everything sitting on the root, until I incorporated it into a Fusebox MVC application. My theory is that it may have been from the slightly heavier load, or more likely (never really thought about it before) because a Fusebox application can only fire one fuseaction (page) at a time... unconfirmed. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single `setInterval`. You could tidy up the code thus:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     refreshCounter = 0;
     $("#header").load("header.cfm").data({refresh: 10});
     $("#main"  ).load("main.cfm"  ).data({refresh:  5});
     $("#footer").load("footer.cfm").data({refresh:  2});
     var refreshHeader = setInterval(function() {
         refreshCounter++;
         $("#header, #main, #footer").each(function(){
             var $this   = $(this);
             var refresh = $this.data('refresh');
             if ((refreshCounter % refresh) == 0) {
                 var cfmFile = this.id + '.cfm';
                 $this.load(cfmFile);
             }
         });
     },
     1000);
});
```

Comment: Nice explanation! Now I learned something new too, ;) I'm glad I didn't say anything else this is cleaner than I was thinking!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. It was your idea of a single timer that set me thinking about how I'd do it without the repetition that Chris was using. I do things like this to stop my grey matter from atrophying!

Comment: @Neil - Thank you for doing this for me. It is very much appreciated. There is only one problem. It doesn't work, apart from showing each section's first item of content

Comment: Chris, just saw your comment. It should work - give me a few minutes and I'll check to see what is wrong.

Comment: Chris, I think I've found the problem. The line "var refresh = $this.data(refresh);" should be "var refresh = $this.data('refresh');". i.e. the parameter to passed to "data()" should be a string - mea culpa. I've edited my answer above accordingly.

Comment: Using jQuery's "data()" method like this enables you to change the frequency of updating "on-the-fly". If at some point you wish to update the footer less frequently, say every 20 seconds, just change it by: $('#footer').data({refresh: 20}); and the frequency will automatically get modified by the function being called by setInterval.

Comment: @Neil - That fixed it. Thanks, but due to concerns of server overload (see davin comments), I have now changed tack and decided to stick with only the main content refreshing. Thank you very much for your input on this. PS. (Again, see davin comments) I would have tested it in the Fusebox application, but being a jQuery dummy, I wasn't sure how allocate the actual page addresses; index.cfm/go/display.header, index.cfm/go/display.main, index.cfm/go/display.footer. If you have time to convert. I would like to check if there is a page load or Fusebox issue... The results would be interesting

Answer (score 3):

If your using jQuery already check out this plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers  , Having multiple setintervterval timings is known to have some issues sometimes. So if you fix your code like Isaac suggests and you find it still dosen't work try this: Instead of making multiple timers I would make 1 scheduler function that fires at your lowest delay(in this case 2000) and then put a counter that increments by 2000 each time and do something like if((counter % 2000) == 0){ action1code;}
if((counter % 6000) == 0) { action2code}
if((counter % 10000) == 0) { action3code}

Hope that's clear, I'm not to sharp at the moment :)

UPDATE: Well I can't test this without having either your code, or writing a whole bunch myself but I believe this might work for you (although my concentration today is pretty low so I may have missed something obvious ;D ). Replace all your code above with this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 count = 10000; // this is so it will load everything the first time through.
 function timerFired () {
      if((count % 2000)==0){
           $("#footer").load("footer.cfm");
      }
      if ((count % 6000)==0) {
           $("#main").load("main.cfm");
      }
      if ((count % 10000)==0){
           $("#header").load("header.cfm");
           count =0;
      }
      count = count + 2000;
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var refreshHeader = setInterval(timerFired(),2000);
  });
 </script>
```

P.S. Don't forget to clear your browsers cache and make sure your .cfm's are changing as you intended if accessed directly from the browser.

Comment: jQuery Timers looked promising, but it was all over the top of my head, and the documentation was vague. I might have another look later, When I feel sharper. I like your idea about a single function, but it is all over the top of my head too

Comment: Well the Isaac I was mentioning seems to have deleted his answer, but basically first you need to get rid of all your extra document ready functions.  You only need 1 $(document).ready in your document.

Comment: Thanks, but alas, it doesn't work. Further... Due to concerns of server overload (see davin comments), I have now changed tack and decided to stick with only the main content refreshing. Thank you very much however, for your input on this